# Convert RDD to DataFrame using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file in spark with following data

`Property ID|Location|Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms|Size|Price SQ Ft|Status`

i have read this file as rdd using

`a=sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt")`

Now I need to convert this rdd into dataframe. I am using the below mentioned command

```
d=spark.createDataFrame(a).toDF("Property ID","Location","Price","Bedrooms","Bathrooms","Size","Price SQ Ft","Status")
```

But i am getting an error as
`TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'str'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the column first:

```
d = spark.createDataFrame(a.map(lambda x: x.split('|'))).toDF("Property ID","Location","Price","Bedrooms","Bathrooms","Size","Price SQ Ft","Status")
```

Or equivalently, calling `toDF` on the RDD directly

```
d = a.map(lambda x: x.split('|')).toDF(["Property ID","Location","Price","Bedrooms","Bathrooms","Size","Price SQ Ft","Status"])
```

In fact, I'd recommend using the Spark CSV reader for this purpose, which could handle the header appropriately too:

```
df = spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt', header=True, inferSchema=True, sep='|')
```

Comment: also include nullValue='NA' for missing data

Comment: Where ? While reading the dataframe after 'sep' option ?

Comment: His comment is irrelevant